# Kendo Grid append a Datarow

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My project is built using MVC along Kendo UI. I am retrieving DataTable as return type from controller.

In Controller:

```
return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtTable));
```

In Script file or . Js file, retrieving data from controller.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Test/Employee/GetEmployeeDtlsActions",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'ID': strUserid,
             'Password' : strPass  

        }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            // Getting data over here.
            // Here we need to append the row to the grid.
            // Need something like gird.addrow(). 
            // Help me how to implement this. 

        }
```

In the above code, How to append one row to the grid and update grid, without any grid refresh? It would helpful if somebody shares any client side code related to this issue.

Comment: SignalR would be an option: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/signalr

Comment: Hi Carsten, thanks for you reply. But my requirement just append a row coming from data parameter at the end of the grid. Either by grid.dataSource.insert / grid.addrow. If it is possible kindly help me with some implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the grid has an [`addRow()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/addrow) method, but it adds an empty row. If you want to add a populated row, use dataSource's [`add()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/add) with an object with values, e.g.:

```
grid.dataSource.add({ Name: "John Doe" });
```